# Create Navbar with Menus in Xamarin forms app

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am making an android app now with help of xamarin forms [xaml] using crossplatform portable project template in Visual studio

While designing home page of my application I like to  have a design like in a normal android app

https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/index.html

But I am using a Navbar and code using in home page is like

```
    public  Homepage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        #region toolbar
        ToolbarItem tbi = null;
        if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.Android)
        {
            tbi = new ToolbarItem("+", "plus", async () =>
            {
                var target_page = new AddStudent();
                await Navigation.PushModalAsync(target_page);
            }, 0, 0);
        }
        ToolbarItems.Add(tbi);
        #endregion             
            this.Title = "Home Page";

    }
```

Its giving a Navigation bar with title and a + icon on right side which helps me to show another page

But how can I design a page like in the link posted with some menu items and events on left side and some menu actions on right side using this NavBar .

Any examples or useful links?

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard of [AppCompat](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/platform-features/android/appcompat/)? See [this](https://blog.xamarin.com/material-design-for-your-xamarin-forms-android-apps/) for starters.

As I understand, you want the application to look on iOS and Android like it was created using Android Material Theme.

You'll clearly need to implement a [custom renderer](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/) for Navigation Bar. That means that you'll have to write custom implementation of the navigation bar for each platform that you'll want to use it on. Also, you'll need to edit part of it from your PCL.

For example, you can use this code to get rid of Xamarin's default icon on the Navigation Bar (add this to your Droid project):

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(NavigationPage), typeof(CustomNavigationRenderer))]
namespace App.Droid
{
    public class CustomNavigationRenderer : NavigationRenderer
    {

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<NavigationPage> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            RemoveAppIconFromActionBar();
        }

        void RemoveAppIconFromActionBar()
        {
            var actionBar = ((Activity)Context).ActionBar;
            actionBar.SetIcon(new ColorDrawable(Color.Transparent.ToAndroid()));
        }
    }
}
```

For every UI object in PCL there is an analogy in each platform. Translating XF objects to native ones is a responsibility of Renderers. When the object is created, `OnElementChanged` is called. From there, you can access native API and make modifications to the element that are not available from the PCL. Like calling `SetIcon` (keep in mind that this code could be Android specific. In most cases, you'll probably need to copy and modify the renderer in order for it to work on other platforms).

In order to add buttons to the right side of the action bar, I would use the following xaml:

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem x:Name="btn"
             Text="Mail"
             Icon="btn_icon.png"
             Clicked="BtnClickHandler" />
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

Than simply back it up with the code behind, like when handling a simple button click:

```
private void BtnClickHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // handling
}
```

You can add several of those.

Also, if you'd like to add context menu to the toolbar and want it to behave like a native android one, you should probably read a little about [animation](http://www.redbitdev.com/cross-platform-animations-using-xamarin-forms/) and draw/animate it yourself, then coordinate it using, say, [AbsoluteLayout](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/absolute-layout/).

Comment: how its going to helpful in making navbar / appbar in a cross platform application

Answer (score 0):

For custom nav bars, I like to just hide the navigation bar and make my own custom one. You do loose some connivence and then the sizing is on you but it gives a ton more flexibility.

You can then just place a colored `BoxView` within a `Grid` and then add buttons to the `Grid`, placing them on top of the `BoxView`.

To hide the navigation bar and the following to your `ContentPage`'s constructor:

```
NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
```

*Edit: That would be fairly easy to do. Like I said, you would make a `Grid`, add a green `BoxView`, and then add an icon to the left and and 3 more to the right.

Something like this:

```
<Grid VerticalOptions="Start"
      HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <BoxView BackgroundColor="Green"
             Grid.Row="0"
             Grid.Column="0"
             Grid.ColumnSpan="5"/>

    <Image Source="hamburger.png"
           Grid.Row="0"
           Grid.Column="0">
        <Image.GestureRecognizer>
            <!-- TODO: Add your gesture stuff -->
        </Image.GestureRecognizer>
    </Image>

    <Label Text="Sheets"
           Grid.Row="0"
           Grid.Column="1"/>

    <Image Source="search.png"
           Grid.Row="0"
           Grid.Column="2">
        <Image.GestureRecognizer>
            <!-- TODO: Add your gesture stuff -->
        </Image.GestureRecognizer>
    </Image>

    <Image Source="folder.png"
           Grid.Row="0"
           Grid.Column="3">
        <Image.GestureRecognizer>
            <!-- TODO: Add your gesture stuff -->
        </Image.GestureRecognizer>
    </Image>

    <Image Source="settingstack.png"
           Grid.Row="0"
           Grid.Column="4">
        <Image.GestureRecognizer>
            <!-- TODO: Add your gesture stuff -->
        </Image.GestureRecognizer>
    </Image>

</Grid>
```

Comment: Is there any possibility of adding AppBar in Universal xamarin forms application ? Since my main aim is to make it like an appbar showed in this link https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/index.html